# ruby with stack-driver credentials fail to authenticate at the circleCI level

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, stack-trace, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am trying to use GCP stack-driver for my ruby project to monitor logs and debugging . the issue is when i copy my credentials file path to my circle ci GOOGLE-APPLICATIION-CREDENTIAL enviroment variable i get an error of failed to authenticate at the circleCI level
this is my error
 `Note: Google::Cloud::Logging is disabled because it failed to authorize with the service. (Unable to read the credential file specified by GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`

> Note: Google::Cloud::Debugger is disabled because it failed to
>   authorize with the service. (Unable to read the credential file
>   specified by GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my solution you have to place the credentials file above the build ,something like this :
 echo ${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS} > ${HOME}/account.json
     GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="${HOME}/account.json"

now the issue is the debugger displays this text

> no source version information provided